# Is there any mocking framework available for Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp

I am working on an application where we are planning to use rabbitmq using springAMQP. To work on this module, I want to find out if there is any mocking framework available to mock the channels.

Thanks & Regards

Amit

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it's not trivial, but the [Spring AMQP framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp) itself uses `Mockito` fairly extensively for mocking. It's pretty easy on the sending side, but the async consuming side is a bit more involved. You can explore the test cases.

However, for more complex scenarios, I find it easier to just use a local rabbitmq, together with a JUnit `@Rule` to only run the tests if rabbit is running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is my test cases run on jenkins where rabbitmq is not available. I had a look at the test classes of the samples as well. They are mocking every rabbitmq class mannually, That is the option I will take in absence of any framework. But many of the frameworks come up with some mocking framework. So, was looking for the possibility of the same. Tried googling it, could not find so reached here.

Comment: I am not aware of a higher-level mocking framework for the rabbitmq java client.

Comment: I also could not find any mocking framework, so I created a stub which could behave as container. Used a map to send message to the consumer attached to the queue.